# Difference Between xlim/ylim and Axis Boundaries

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-2.6

Considering the following chart produced with matplotlib 1.1.1:

[image]

`ax.get_ylim = (30, 90)`.  When I run the following code:

```
ax.plot_date(dates_to_plot, y_obs2)
foo = ax.get_ylim()
ax.fill_between(dates_to_plot, foo[0], y_obs2)
```

the fill is between y_obs2 (the blue freeze line) and 30 -- which is expected.  What I want is to fill between y_obs2 and 20 (or whatever the lower boundary is for the chart at that time.)

If I replace `foo[0]` with just plain `0`, the area below the horizontal line is completely filled, but that's not optimal because the chart's lower boundary is changed to 0. Further, y_obs1 (the temperature) may become negative (unfortunately!).  I have been unable to find a method to fill the area between the y_obs2 line and the chart's lower boundary--whatever it might be.

Is there a method that I'm not seeing that can provide a tuple of the chart's ***outside*** boundaries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to set the ylimits [`auto=False`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_ylim) to ensure that they aren't re-calculated when you change the plotted data.

```
ax.plot_date(dates_to_plot, y_obs2)

# Get the current ylims
foo = ax.get_ylim()

# Prevent the axes ylims from changing automatically with new plots
ax.set_ylim(auto=False)

ax.fill_between(dates_to_plot, foo[0], y_obs2)

# You can always manually specify the ylims as well
# ax.set_ylim((lower, upper))
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  It's not something that I would've considered--setting something equal to itself--but it does work.  Much appreciated.

Comment: @DaveL17 That's one way. I just updated it with a more logical way

Comment: That does clarify things. That effectively gives the freedom to set ylim to whatever I want.  Cheers.

Comment: @DaveL17 Well you can always do `ax.set_ylim((lower, upper))` to specify explicit limits.

Comment: Yeah, I missed the chance to edit my comment--I didn't realize that I could come back and set ylim after the plot.